# How to receive message when activity is inactive?

Tags: android

I'm using BroadcastReceiver in activity to receive message from others services.  It works well, but the problem is that

**When my app goes to the background, the BroadcastReceiver will be unregister from the activity.  so the messages which are received before the activity go to front will be lost.**

How to handle the case?

Comment: For what action you have used Broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Scenario A**: Only The Activity
If you only need to receive the broadcast when you have an activity in the foreground, have the activity register the BroadcastReceiver using registerReceiver(). As @MisterSquonk indicated, you would register the receiver in onResume() and unregister it in onPause().

**Scenario B**: Activity If In Foreground, Else Other; Ordered Broadcast
If you want the foreground activity to handle the broadcast, but you want something else to happen if that activity is not in the foreground (e.g., raise a Notification), and the broadcast is an ordered broadcast (e.g., incoming SMS), then you would still use the Scenario A solution, but with a higher-priority IntentFilter (see setPriority()). In addition, you would register a BroadcastReceiver via a  element in the manifest, with a lower-priority  for the same broadcast. In the activity's BroadcastReceiver, call abortBroadcast() to consume the event and prevent it from reaching your manifest-registered BroadcastReceiver.

**Scenario C**: Activity If In Foreground, Else Other; Regular Broadcast
If Scenario B almost fits, but the broadcast you are listening for is not an ordered broadcast, you will need to start with Scenario B. However, have the broadcast that both receivers have in their respective filters be one of your own, using a private action string as @MisterSquonk suggested. In addition, have another BroadcastReceiver registered in the manifest, whose  is for the real broadcast you're listening for. That receiver would simply call sendOrderedBroadcast() to send out the ordered broadcast that the other receivers are listening on.

**Scenario D**: Activity Regardless of Foreground
If some activity of yours needs to know about the broadcast, and it does not matter whether or not it is in the foreground, you need to rethink what you mean by that. Usually, this really means that the broadcast affects your data model in some way, in which case your concern should not be to let the activities know, but rather to update your data model, and use your already-existing "let the activities know about the data model change" logic handle the rest.

If, however, you are convinced that this is not part of your data model, you can implement Scenario B or Scenario C, plus stick some information in a static data member. Your activities can examine that static data member in onResume() to pick up the information about the broadcast when they return to the foreground.

If you're thinking "but, what if my process is terminated between the broadcast and the other activity coming to the foreground?", then your broadcast really is updating your data model, per the opening paragraph of this scenario.

If you're thinking "but, I want to update an activity that is doing work in the background", then the activity in question is broken. Activities should never be doing work in the background. That work should be delegated to some form of service, and there's a whole related set of scenarios for getting a broadcast to the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest, it will always be active and be called even if the application is closed.